# how to style links on my menu, without changing the links on the rest of the site?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Here is the [site](http://www.airfieldcards.com) I am trying to change, in the menu on the left.

The links are within a list set `ul li` and I have given the menu holding a `div` class of `.vince`.

In my custom `CSS` file I have tried everything I can imagine, with no success on the color of the text, nor decoration.

I can however, easily change the `background-color: #4266B1` with no trouble.  Please help, I've spend DAYS trying to solve this.

I have tried so far.

```
.vince {
background-color:#0000ff; /*#4266b1;*/
    color:#FF0000;
    padding-top:5px;
    padding-left:15px;
    padding-botom:50px;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-decoration-color: white;

}
```

No good.

```
.vince a:link, .vince a: visited, .vince a:active {
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: #ff0000;
    color:white;
}
```

No good.

```
.vince ul li a:default
.vince ul li a:active
.vince ul li a:link
.vince ul li a:focus
.vince ul li a:enabled
{
    text-decoration: none;
    color:#ffffff;
```

}
No good.  Plus, a myriad of other alternatives found on here and the web. This is a **bootstrap** site, and I have left the bootstrap `CSS` file alone.  This is a `custom.css` file, which I know it works, because I can change the background of the menu easily.

Comment: `.vince-class li a { color: red;}` ?

Comment: Looks like your container class is `vince-class` not `vince`.

Comment: I would also suggest making your class names something that explains what the element is, rather than your own name. It's easier to read code if the class names are descriptive of the elements they are styling. In this situation `menu-container` or something similar would be a more suitable class name.

Comment: Thanks, for your answer, but the syntax of the class names doesn't really mater.  I simply called it that, so that I knew it was me.  I will change it to something meaningful as soon as I get it going.  it's getting it to work that's my challenge.  Answer below has sorted it, or so it seems.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try with the `>` operator? I did it with no problem, let me show you.

This is what I wrote:

```
.vince-class > ul > li > a {
    color: red;
}
```

And this is what I get: [http://www.airfieldcards.com/b/index.php](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dK5Un.png)

Tell me if it work.

Comment: Brilliant, thanks mate, that DID work.  I will now continue in my localhost environment, and will update the site as soon as I have it all as desired.

Comment: Although it worked on the main links.  When you click on the items... and go to the "further drop down items" they are still styled as before.

        .vince > ul > li > a  {
        background-color:#4266B1;
        color: white;
        text-decoration: none;
        font-style: bold;
    }

Comment: I saw that you changed the style for `.sidemenu`, so if you want to apply this style to every `a` element inside the `div` with the class `.sidemenu`, you can only write `.sidemenu a`. It will applie the style to every `a` element inside the `<div class="sidemenu">` no matter where it is inside. The exemple I wrote above mean this: apply this style the element `a` wich is inside an `li` element wich is inside an `ul` element wich is inside an element with the class `.vince-class`.  So only use `.sidemenu { color: red }` and it will apply `color: red` to every `a` element in `.sidemenu`.

Comment: Thanks for the info mate.  It's now sorted as you can see.

Answer (score 0):

`.vince-class a { ... }` and similar is sufficient, you just have to be careful about the class name

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple solutions for this problem:

Strict solution:

```
div.vince-class > ul > li > a {
    color: blue;
}
```

Non-strict solution:

```
div.vince-class ul li a {
    color: blue;
}
```

Both solutions should work. For more information:
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp

Comment: Brilliant, thanks Milan.  The second one did work.  However.  I can't seem to get rid of the bullets that are default on the list items li.  I have tried text-decoration: none; and list-style: none; but both have no effect.

Edit:  Adding the following to the CSS to remove the bullets DID work.
    .vince-style ul li {
    list-style-type: none;
    }